# How To Sychronize Code In TIdTCPServer::Execute

Tags: c++builder, indy

I have VCL code in the TIdTCPServer::Execute method that needs to be Syncronized, how can I do this?

```
void __fastcall Tdata::bcServerExecute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
  String json = AContext->Connection->Socket->ReadLn();
  TJSONObject* jo = (TJSONObject*)TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(json);
  if (jo != 0)
  {
    TJSONPair* jp = (TJSONPair*)jo->Get("text");
    String text = jp->JsonValue->Value();

    jp = (TJSONPair*)jo->Get("font_size");
    int font_size = _wtoi(jp->JsonValue->Value().c_str());

    int tw = 0;
    double text_width = 0.0;
    //================================
    TCanvas* canvas = new TCanvas();
    if (canvas)
    {
      canvas->Handle = GetDC(0);
      canvas->Font->Size = font_size;
      tw = canvas->TextWidth(text);
      double ppi = Screen->PixelsPerInch;
      text_width = double(tw) / ppi;
      ReleaseDC(0,canvas->Handle);

      delete canvas;
    }
    String buf = String(text_width);
    //==================================
    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn(buf); 
  }
}
```

The code is not surprisingly periodically deadlocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in this code needs to be delegated to the main UI thread via Synchronize.

However, when using a `TCanvas` in a worker thread, you do need to [`Lock()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCustomCanvas.Lock) it while you are using it, otherwise the main UI thread will interfere with it in the background (**UPDATE:** specifically, the main UI thread frequently releases `HDC`s belonging to *unlocked* `TBitmap.Canvas` and `TControlCanvas` objects, even ones being used by worker threads. You are OK if you use `TCanvas` itself, though).

Alternatively, simply replace the `TCanvas` with the corresponding Win32 API function calls instead ([`CreateFontIndirect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183500.aspx), [`GetTextExtentPoint32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144938.aspx)), then you don't have to worry about locking anything.

Comment: Turns out it was invalid JSON that was causing the "deadlock".  You got me looking in the right places though.

Comment: Malformed JSON should not be causing deadlocks.  Delphi's JSON parser would simply throw an exception if it can't parse the JSON, which in turn would disconnect the TCP client since your server's `OnExecute` event handler is not catching exceptions. Does your server's `OnDisconnect` or `OnException` event handler(s) do anything that need to be synced with the main UI thread? If so, and you are not sync'ing that, that could cause deadlocks.

Comment: There should definitely be a try/finally used, the client must be replied to with something or it will hang waiting.

Comment: @user1455270 like I said, an uncaught exception will simply disconnect the client. But you are correct that a `try/finally` (or a smart pointer) should be used to avoid memory leaks.